# Elisp destructive operation warning?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Emacs gives useful warnings on byte-compilation.
Is there a plugin that adds warnings about destructive operations being used?
So that when I write code like this:

```
(defun get-countdown ()
  (let ((x (number-sequence 0 10)))
    (message (format "%s" (sort x #'>)))
    x))#
```

Emacs complains:

```
temp.el:4:5:Warning: using variable modified by `sort'.
```

Or maybe something like `elisp-newbie-mode` that highlights all destructive functions?

Comment: That would be neat, but the byte-compiler does not do a sufficiently sophisticated analysis to give you that kind of info.  As for highlighting calls to `sort`, `nreverse`, etc... it's clearly possible, but I don't know of any ready made package for that.  Looks like you could write one?

Comment: I'd like to try do the one with the analysis sometime.
Maybe I could temporarily redefine lambda to track what is done with
its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I sent a patch to Emacs Dev today that adds this to the byte compiler.

It's a start anyway.  See Emacs [bug #15122](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15122).

Comment: Thanks, it's a start. Does this generate a false positive for `(setq x (sort x #'>))`?

Comment: Yes.  Well, it issues the warning.  (But it is only arguably a false positive.)  Like most byte-compiler warnings, it is not extremely savvy.